# looking for title of young adult book of city under glass dome and all wore identification tracking bracelets

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Identification of young adult dystopian novel, possibly written in 1960s, where all inhabitants of a city lived under glass dome and wore id tracking bracelets.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Could you add any more details possibly?  This is fairly little to go on so any other details you can add would be of great use!  Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 6):

[Logan's Run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run)?  Dome: check. ID bracelets: check. 1967: check. Volunteer for death at 21 or else you're chased down and killed by a gun that ignites every pain nerve in your body: check (dystopian).

And a [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074812/) too!